# Efficient way to see if single array with certain set of value is present in 2d array containing several single array? Swift 4

Tags: swift

Here is brief Swift 4 code:

```
let result = six49(draws: 1, lines: 5)

var collection = result.appendArrays()
var winningNumberToday: [Int] = result.winningNumber()
```

`result` instance is initialized with `six49` class. It contains a function called `appendArrays()`, which generates certain lines of six sets of numbers (Five lines, in this case). Variable `collection` receives output of numbers in a type of `[[Int]]`. Output looks something like this:

> [[1, 6, 19, 28, 29, 47], [5, 10, 13, 14, 18, 29], [5, 8, 16, 20, 35,
>   39], [6, 8, 11, 16, 42, 47], [3, 23, 26, 31, 34, 49]]

Another function of `result` instance produces one set of six numbers. It is stored in a variable called `winningNumberToday` (Type of `[Int]`). And the output looks like this:

> [6, 10, 15, 30, 33, 45]

I want to write few lines of code that will efficiently determine whether `winningNumberToday` array (`[Int]`) values matches any of value in `collection` array `[[Int]]`.

I tried something like this, but it is not working:

```
collection.contains(where: winningNumberToday)
```

It would give me an error message like this:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:82:28: error: cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type '([Int]) throws -> Bool'
collection.contains(where: winningNumberToday)
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `collection.contains(where: { $0.contains(winningNumberToday) })`

Comment: @JamesRyu It's Swift convention for data ypes (such as your class) to use UpperCamelCase. I would suggest you rename it to `Six49`

Comment: Thank you @Alexander. I definitely read that in documentation but forgot because my brain is so overloaded with concepts from reading documentations all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
if let ix = collection.index(where: {$0 == winningNumberToday}) {
    print("Index is \(ix)")
}
OR 
if collection.contains(where: {$0 == winningNumberToday}) {
    print("You won!")
}
```

Comment: Sigh, one day we'll have conditional conformances, and we will finally be able to treat arrays as `Equatable`, by just using `contains(_:)`